# tableview scrollview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to make a UITableView, which has many columns, so the whole cell can't display the all data, and the first column shows titles, this row can't move flatly, but other rows can move flatly.
I tried adding UITableView to UIScrollView, but failed

Is there any ways to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a custom TableViewCell to achieve this properly.

EDIT:
A quick example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MultiColumnTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIButton *leftButton;
    UIButton *middleButton;
    UIButton *rightButton;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *leftButton;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *middleButton;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *rightButton;

@end


#import "MultiColumnTableViewCell.h"

    @implementation MultiColumnTableViewCell

    @synthesize leftButton;
    @synthesize middleButton;
    @synthesize rightButton;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [leftButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            leftButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            leftButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            leftButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

            middleButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [middleButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            middleButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            middleButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            middleButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

            rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [rightButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            rightButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            rightButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            rightButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @end
```

Quick usage in tableview:

```
- (MultiColumnTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MultiColumnTableViewCell *cell = (MultiColumnTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MultiColumnTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    float tableviewWidth = self.myTableView.frame.size.width/3;
    int irow = indexPath.row;

    NSString *cellValue = myString;

    cell.leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableviewWidth, 64.0);
    cell.leftButton.tag = someTag;
    [cell.leftButton setTitle:cellValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:cell.leftButton];

    cellValue = someOtherString;
    cell.middleButton.frame = CGRectMake(tableviewWidth, 0, tableviewWidth, 64.0);
    cell.middleButton.tag = someOtherTag;
    [cell.middleButton setTitle:cellValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.middleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someOtherAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:cell.middleButton];

    cellValue = yetAnotherString
    cell.rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(tableviewWidth*2, 0, tableviewWidth, 64.0);
    cell.rightButton.tag = yetAnotherTag;
    [cell.rightButton setTitle:cellValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yetAnotherAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:cell.rightButton];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Check edit for a quick example on multi column tableviewcells

Comment: but how do i fix the first column?

Comment: you can have the title labels move along with your movement while the other labels below move left or right. This you are able to do if you can update the offset of the titlelabels. Aka, move your title labels as much as you move to the left or right.